# Formatting DateTime to string

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, string-formatting

The following code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 9, 13, 14, 34, 0);
string s = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "\n");
textBox1.AppendText(s + "\n");
textBox1.AppendText(dt.ToString() + "\n");
```

produces the following output in the textbox:

```
13.09.2013 1441.28
09.13.2013
13.09.2013 1434.00
```

From the first line of the output, it is clear that in the regional setting of my PC, date/time is formatted as `date.month.year HHmm.ss`.

The second line of the output is confusing to me. Though I specified `MM/dd/yyyy` format for the variable `s`, the `DateTime` object is formatted as `MM.dd.yyyy`. Why?

This is a C# WPF program on .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/` is the placeholder for your current culture's date separator. If you want to enforce it as separator you have to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
string s = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

> The appropriate localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property of the current or specified
>   culture.

---

The same is true if you want to parse a `string` to `DateTime`.

Following throws a `FormatException` if your current culture's actual date-separator is not `/`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("09/13/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

works always:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("09/13/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: +1 Wow, never even realised that, because for me the date separator is `"/"`. Good catch.